# How to render HTML tags sent as Node JS variable in EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, blogs

*Disclaimer: I asked this question when I was clearly a noob, but I am leaving this up hoping it can help someone in the future.*

**Context:**
Image to make the question more clear: [My issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzAcC.png)

I'm working on a Node JS + EJS blog application.
I have a separate page(www.domain/compose) where I can write the title and the body for my post. I can then access this post through www.domain/posts/post-title

Like shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzAcC.png), I want to send over HTML tags that can be rendered.

I want to send **any HTML tags to my liking** in whatever order I want. Not only the em and img tags.

**My Node Server code:**

```
app.post("/compose", (req, res)=>{
  const post = {
    'title': req.body.newPostTitle,
    'body': req.body.newPostContent,
  };
  posts.push(post);
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get("/posts/:postName", (req, res)=>{
  const urlSuffix = req.params.postName;
  posts.forEach((post)=>{
    const postURL = lodash.kebabCase(post.title);
    if(urlSuffix===postURL || urlSuffix===post.title){
      console.log("Match Found!");
      res.render("post", {postTitle:post.title, postBody: post.body});
      }else{
        console.log("Not a match")
      }
  });
});
```

**My EJS Template code:**

```
<%- include('partials/header') -%>

<h1><%=postTitle%></h1>
<p><%=postBody%></p>

<%- include('partials/footer') -%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! All I had to do was change my .ejs template from:

```
<%=postBody%>
```

to

```
<%-postBody%>
```

Comment: YES! Thanks so much, I wouldn't have found it without you.